# Android setImageDrawable called on icon in listview makes list dissapear

Tags: android, android-listview

I use menu in my application where all menu items are stored in a list. When method getView is called I specify item name and icon. For icons I use StateListDrawable (but I also tried with simple color drawable). The problem is that whenever I try to scroll my menu and getView is called, my whole list disappears. I pinned down the cause of it which is an image view method setImageDrawable(); If I comment it out, everything works fine. This method is called on another thread because I first need to download image. If I move setImageDrawable() code to getView method directly it will load everything and menu won't disappear, but the delay is too long before image is downloaded and menu is usable.

Code that works:

```
icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
icon.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN));
icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Code that makes menu dissapear.

```
context.getNetworkManager().execute(new ImageRunnable() {
    boolean success = true;
    @Override
    public void run(Bitmap image) {
        if (image == null) {
            success = false;
        }
        final Bitmap selectedImage = image;
        context.getNetworkManager().execute(new ImageRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(Bitmap image) {
                if (image == null) {
                    success = false;
                }
                if (success) {
                    StateListDrawable icons = new StateListDrawable();
                    icons.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                        new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), selectedImage));
                    icons.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected},
                            new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), selectedImage));
                    icons.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_selected},
                            new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), image));
                    icon.setImageDrawable(icons);
                    //icon.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN));
                    icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this? This happens on emulator and Galaxy SII, but not on Galaxy SIII.

Answer (score 0):

Android won't allow you to modify UI components from a non UI thread. With other words, you can't call: `icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` from `run()` method of a thread. My assumption is that this is exactly what is happening in `ImageRunnable`.

Inspect the LogCat for any exception messages.

Perhaps you could extract that part of code which initializes the  `StateListDrawable` in the constructor of your adapter, so it to be called only once, and then in `getView()` set the image drawable without using a thread.

Comment: No. I use runOnUiThread() somewhere deep in network manager, so this shouldn't be a problem.